# How can I get a field's value from a global based on a url segment?

Tags: field, globals

I have a rich text field with a handle of `myTextField` that I have included in a global set called `firstGlobalSet`.

What If I created another global set called `secondGlobalSet` and included the same field `myTextField`.

How could I get the correct field from the correct global set based on url segment?

For example, `mysite.com/first` or `mysite.com/second`

Answer (score 2):

You will need to access a few things.

- The url segment you need (for example the last segment)
- The global set name
- The field handle name

You can use [getLastSegment](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.request#getLastSegment) to access the last url segment.

Using the global set names above let's say I have a url like this:

```
mysite.com/first

{% set segment = craft.request.getLastSegment() %}  // first
```

I know I've got a global set called `firstGlobalSet`, and now I've got `first`. We just need to put them together. You can use Craft's 
[getSetByHandle](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.globals#getSetByHandle) method to access the global set via its handle.

```
{% set global = craft.globals.getSetByHandle(segment ~ 'GlobalSet') %}
{{ global }} // firstGlobalSet
```

Now that we've got the correct global set, we can get to the field we need. In this case it's `myTextField`.

```
{{ global.myTextField }}
```